# Trouble sending dynamic list from app script to HTML for Sidebar

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I am trying to pull a range from a google sheet and use it to populate select options. I have tried many different variations and I was able to get it working using html += directly in app script. However I am trying to do it with a seperate html file and I can not get the list to populate at all. The current attempt looks like this.

**Appscript:**

```
    function showSidebar2() {
    var url = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Rk8zGtZm93w86IAz7mVDqNqxq4YnGI6Ii6J5hL6CrZ0/edit#gid=0"; 
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    var ws = ss.getSheetByName("driv");
    var rng= ws.getRange('A:E')
    var driver= rng.getValues();
      var driverList = driver.map(function(row) {
      return row[0];
    }).filter(function(driver) {
      return driver !== "";
    });

    var userInterface = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('remdriver.html')
      .setTitle('Driver Menu')
      .setWidth(300);
      userInterface.append(driverList.join(","));
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
   }
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="sched-field sched-field-r0c0m3i1"><label for="r0c0m3i1">Select Driver:</label><select id="driverList" name="email" required="">
        <? driverList.forEach(e => { ?>;
                <option value="<?= e ?>">
                <? }); ?>
        </select>
```

The sidebar works properly however the list does not populate is only shows "" and help would be appreciated!

**ALSO BONUS POINTS** if you could tell me how to get the sidebar to close after submit button is hit (different Sidebar issue)
Everything works the way it should but it just stays open. Currently have:

```
    <script>
    function submitForm() {
       google.script.run.appendRowFromFormSubmit(document.getElementById("addDriverForm"))
       .host.close();
    }
    </script>
```

Would be fine if it closes but if not I would also be happy adding a loadbar for the function or loading gif with success handler but I have not been successful with that either :/

Comment: Where is the evaluation of your scriplets performed?

Comment: I apologize I am still working through all of this and learning. Would that be done via script on html side or in the sidebar function?

Comment: Well you are using scriplets and they get evaluated on the server via the template.evaluate() method and that will return an htmloutput object and getContent() will provide the html with scriptlets having been evaluated.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Why the Java tag? The question is not related to java code. Please edit the tag.

Comment: That makes sense, I think one of the other ones I had was closer. Let me look into those and I will see what I can come up with!